# How to use {% url %} tag in django

Tags: django, django-templates

[image: Screenshot 1]

I am getting this error `dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required` while using url tag in my django application. Why?

```
<a href="{% url 'Review.AddBook' %}">ADD BOOK</a> my url code

url(regex=r'^AddBook/$',view='views.AddBook',name='Review.AddBook'), # my url code

//My view function
def AddBook(request):
    c={'page_title':Constants.addBookTitle,'form':BookInfoForm()}
    c['booktypes']=Business.BookInformation().GetBookType()
    return render_to_response('AddBook.html',context=c,context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

Comment: Dunno. Probably something to do with some code you've written. I reckon the error message probably tells you, though.

Comment: if I am using same thing in Django 1.4 , it's working fine but in higher version of 1.5 it is not working.

Comment: this error is happening in your `urls.py` file or `views.py`? could you post the view associated with that url?

Comment: That cod looks correct, so my guess is that the error is from another part of your code.

Comment: I added image also of error code .Have a look

Comment: you should try renaming your url, keep it simple like `review_addbook` and do not use `.` for naming